# Check if current time is in weekends Python

Tags: python, date

I am trying to code something like the following code. 
I would like my code to do nothing between the Friday 11PM and before the monday 1AM which should be the variable bgn and end but I don't manage to code the day and hour in thoese two variables.

```
import datetime

Now = datetime.datetime.now()      

bgn = 'Should be Friday 11 PM'
end = 'Should be Monday 1 AM'

if Now>bgn and Now<end:
    pass
elif:
    ...
```

Comment: `Now` isn't a string, but you are comparing it to strings.

Comment: also: `bgn` and `end` are not DateTimes and you compare them to a datetime. Create them as datetime and you can easily do `if bgn < Now < end: pass`

Comment: what are you even trying to do with bgn and end. Store datetime in bgn & end to actually compare

Comment: This is what I am trying to do but I have somme errors I don't manage do do it with the correct way

Comment: Try to do `print(type(Now))` and see the type of it which is not same as string **bgn**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at datetime weekday() method which gives you the number of the day in the week.

Basically (if I understand well) you dont want to do something in theses three differents cases:

1. If the day is a saturday or sunday (it means in day 5 and 6)
2. If the day is friday (day 4) but the hour is above 23h
3. If the day is monday (day 0) but the hour is before 1h

So you can do something like this:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.weekday() in [5, 6] or (now.weekday() == 4 and now.hour >= 23) or (now.weekday() == 0 and now.hour <= 1):
   pass
else:
   (do stuff)
```

I'm pretty sure you can do something shorter and smarter but it do the trick.